# Targeting a div externally on the page using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a child div slide into view within a parent div upon a user clicking on a text link which is located outside of either divs.

It's basically used for an advanced search criteria section for a search page, so when the user enters the page, by default I'm trying to either position it off a bit(to hide it) initially until the user clicks on the text link which makes it toggle and slides into view. (advanced search criteria is like linkedin to a horizontal slide was necessary)

here is what I got which does not seem to hide it when user enters and also does not allow me to position a text link externally on the same page.

The CSS

```
 <style type="text/css">
.slide {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden
}

.slide .inner {
bottom: 0;
width: 220px;
}

</style>
```

The dreaded link text in the parent div I cant seem to relocate anywhere:

```
<div id="slidebottom" class="slide">
<a href="#" class="toggle">Slide it</a>
<div class="inner">
```

The Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        var $marginLefty = $(this).next();
        $marginLefty.animate({
            marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'), 10) == 0 ?
                $marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple example for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/WJ7Zp/

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).next().animate({width: 'toggle'});
});
```

Comment: It seems to hide the div initially as expected.  The only thing is that it now slides in from the left instead of the right and the text link cannot be used outside of the parent div for some reason.    updated jsfiddle to show link not work when outside of parent div  http://jsfiddle.net/WJ7Zp/1/

Comment: if you need to place the link somewhere else, give .inner an id and use $("#id").animate(....  This stuff is very elementary and thoroughly documented at jquery.com

Comment: It seems once I toggle from a collapsed state a second time and try expand it, the div appears behind all other divs on the page instead of pushing them as it did the first time. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: So far I've only allowed the user to expand the div and restricted them from collapsing it due to the current behavior of the div showing up behind the second time around.

code used to show only once:

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.toggle').click(function() {
    var $marginLefty = $(this).next();
$("#inners").animate({width: 'show'});

    });
});
</script>